# how to customize web authentication login pop-up?

Tags: authentication

I'd like to customize web authentication login pop-up, change "restricted access" to some instruction words. Is there anyway I can implement it? Thanks.

[authentication popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkGEm.png)